# Drawing and Animation in iOS

Tags: ios, animation, canvas, drawing, processing

My background is Processing and HTML5 Canvas. Now I want to write an iOS app, and include some kind of canvas, where I can draw shapes and images on, similar to a sketch in Processing (2D).

What's the common / most simple way to do that in iOS development? I would also appreciate links to good tutorials to get started, if you know some.

Comment: What kind of drawing/Animation u want to do? Ur question is not clear enough.

Comment: Basically I want to draw circles, rectangles, lines, move them, scale them and maybe have a step loop to do some animation.

Comment: You want to draw them by code or free hand drawing(Let user to draw shapes)?

Comment: By code. Right now for example I have a Processing sketch, which I want to translate into some language / framework, so it can work on iOS. (replace click with touch events, ...)

Comment: you could just use HTML5 drawing in a UIWebView since you're already familiar with it.

Comment: Ok, is that the "way to go"? What about OpenGL? Then I head about Quartz and CoreAnimation, what is normally used?

Comment: I've used all of those - it just depends on what you need it for and what you're comfortable with. If you need fast 3d animation, use OpenGL.  CoreAnimation is relatively easy to implement but you can also do a lot of the same things in HTML5 animation.

Answer (score 1):

The simple way is, assuming you are not using any Java Libraries in Processing, use processing.js and your .pde file in something like PhoneGap so that you can compile it to native code for iOS. I have done this and it works well although the performance is simular to what you would get in mobile safari with a html5 app.